# Непонятное поведение программы на C++

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "typeinfo"
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <istream>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    string a, b;
    int A, B;
    int result = NULL;
    int flag_a = 0;
    int flag_b = 0;
    char op;
    do {
        do
        {
            if (result != NULL)
                a = result;
            if (result == NULL)
            {
                cout << "Введите первый операнд: ";
                getline(cin, a);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
            {
                if (!isdigit(a[i]))
                {
                    flag_a++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag_a > 0)
            {
                cout << "Вы ввели не число, пожалуйста повторите попытку." << endl;
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                flag_a = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                A = atoi(a.c_str());
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        do {
            cout << "Введите операцию: ";
            cin >> op;
            if ((op != '+') && (op != '-') && (op != '*') && (op != '/'))
            {
                cout << "Вы ввели некорректную операцию" << endl;
                cout << "Возможные операции: + - * /" << endl;
                cin.clear(); // на случай, если предыдущий ввод завершился с ошибкой
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                result = NULL;
                continue;
            }
            else break;
        } while (true);
        do {
            cout << "Введите второй операнд: ";
            getline(cin, b);
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
            {
                if (!isdigit(b[i]))
                {
                    flag_b++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag_b > 0)
            {
                cout << b << endl;
                cout << "Вы ввели не число, пожалуйста повторите попытку." << endl;
                system("pause");
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                flag_b = 0;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                B = atoi(b.c_str());
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        if (op == '+')
        {
            result = A + B;
            cout << result << endl;
        }
        if (op == '-')
        {
            result = A - B;
            cout << result << endl;
        }
        if (op == '*')
        {
            result = A*B;
            cout << result << endl;
        }
        if (op == '/')
        {
            result = A / B;
            cout << result << endl;
        }
    } while (true);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Добрый день всем! Помогите новичку, пожалуйста. На практике дали задание написать несложный калькулятор с поддержкой базовых математических функций - сложения, умножения, вычитания и деления. Калькулятор должен контролировать корректность введенных пользователем данных, что я и попытался реализовать. Проверка первого операнда на то, является ли он числом проходит успешно, но дальше происходит что-то не совсем мне понятное. Как только мы доходим до присвоения значения второму операнду программа присваивает ему значение первого и говорит, что это не число. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Уважаемый автор, ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, со значением термина "неопределённое поведение", например, здесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: 1) Учитесь пользоваться дебагером. Посмотрите, что считала программа в качестве второго числа. Ошибка здесь выйдет сразу. 2) Более правильный вариант использовать не getline. Изучите, как ведёт себя `std::cin << number`, если number число, а ввели не число. 3) стоит использовать функции. Например вынести в функции чтение чисел. 4) не стоит использовать while(true) и do while(true), а внутри break. Это очень тяжело читается. Условие выхода стоит питать в условии цикла, вместо true. Переписать так не сложно.

Comment: @Дмитрий Зинченко, Может подскажете? Сделал все как вы говорили, структурировал код, создал функции. Функцию atoi заменил на stoi. Теперь получаю следующее: "Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x76B22CF2 в calculator.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::invalid_argument по адресу памяти 0x009BF52C." То есть stoi почему-то ругается на то, что я передаю ей строчку b. По идее. Из-за чего это может происходить? Первую строку она нормально обрабатывает.

Comment: Поставьте на строку после `getline(cin, b);` breakpoint. Посмотрите, что считала программа в качестве b.

Answer (score 1):

1. Команда `getline` конфликтует с оператором `>>`. Используйте только
   `cin >> a ;` и не будет проблем.
2. Команда `a = result;` делает не то, что вы думаете. Вы строке присваиваете один символ с кодом математического результата. Нужно присваивание числа строке делать по-другому. Например `a = std::to_string(result);`.
3. Не пользуйтесь `NULL`. Он имеет тип указателя, а вы присваиваете указатель целому числу. Можно просто написать `0`.

Comment: А какие могут быть альетернативы getline? Просто cin, как я понимаю, не работает с типом string.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator>>/